# Adding items to a list from a loop with conditions

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to add some items to a list, but only if condition is true.
My function is actually storing null data when condition is false.

```
hit_list = for {_mob, %{id: id}} <- get_mob_list(state.mobs) do
  if condition do
    id
  end
end
```

Output:

```
[null, "2"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this with `for`:

```
hit_list = for {_mob, %{id: id}} <- get_mob_list(state.mobs), condition do
  id
end
```

For example:

```
iex(1)> for i <- 1..10, i + 1 < 4, do: i
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [Enum.filter/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) Would be a more idiomatic approach

```
Enum.filter(1..10, fn(x) -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

---

I originally missed the requirement about needing to only pull out the ID. In that case, you can use [List.foldr/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#foldr/3).

```
x = Enum.zip(1..10, [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g,:h,:i,:j])
[{1, :a}, {2, :b}, {3, :c}, {4, :d}, {5, :e}, {6, :f}, {7, :g}, {8, :h}, {9, :i}, {10, :j}]
List.foldr(x, [], fn({x, _}, acc) -> if rem(x, 2) == 0, do: [x | acc], else: acc end)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: OP also wants to extract the `id` with a pattern though which means you'll need a call to `Enum.map/2` after this.

Comment: How would you return the `id` though? `Enum.filter/2` returns the original element if the predicate function returns a truthy value.

Comment: I missed the requirement about pattern matching. I will edit my answer to include `List.foldr/3`.

Answer (score 2):

While both answers here so far are perfectly valid, I’d come with more generic approach that allows more sophisticated filtering: [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)

```rb
reducer = fn
  i, acc when i + 1 < 4 -> [i | acc]
  _i, acc -> acc
end

1..10
|> Enum.reduce([], reducer)
|> :lists.reverse()
#⇒ [1, 2]
```

Here it looks like an overkill, but it’s more powerful than both other ways and comes to the rescue as a last resort when neither [comprehensions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1), nor plain [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) do not help.

*Sidenote:* last call to `:lists.reverse` is required because `reduce` reverses the input upfront.

Comment: Also note that you'll have to use `if` instead of guards to call non-guard compatible functions. With `for` you're allowed to call anything in a filter expression.

Comment: @Dogbert well, yes, at a cost of efficiency. Guards are faster.